# How to set text in form from another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I'm working on a term paper that performs operations with complex numbers. Application looks like this:
[image]

If you click on "Calculate", will calculate the operands and the result is displayed in a new dialog box. So I have two dialogs - a main window (up on pic) to display the read result (down on pic). Unfortunately I was not able to save result in the main dialog box, which is then written to a text file. There is important piece of code:
[image]

Thank you for ideas.

Comment: Just expose a property on the second form class with the text result and then after `ShowDialog` you can just grab the result from that property and use it.

Comment: Really you have taken screenshots of the code instead of copy and paste it!

Comment: @DarrenKopp: Because I don't see this property in main window. I used this declaration of property: public string ResultOut { set; get; }

Comment: @FeliceM: Thanks for the reply, but isn't the subject.

Comment: @Vland: Same problem that I wrote to DarrenKopp. No visible.

Comment: @avalagne save that result in a Public Property, visible by both forms and then call it from wherever you want.

Comment: @Vland: Yeah, i have public string ResultOut { set; get; }, but it isn't visible in second Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `MainForm` class declare a property as

```
public class MainForm:Form
{
  public string CalculationResult { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
  //Your code here
  ...
  ...
}
```

then on method of calculate change it to

```
  if(resultBool!=null)
  {
    CalculationResult = resultBool.ToString());
    formResult dlg=new formResult(CalculationResult);
    dlg.Owner=this
    dlg.StartPosition=FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    dlg.ShowDialog();
  }
  else
  {
    ...
    ...
    //your code
    ...
    ...
  }
```

and change the following line

```
  sw.WriteLine("Result: ");
```

to

```
  sw.WriteLine("Result: " + CalculationResult);
```

in `saveData` method which is in `MainForm` class. Hope this will work for you. Happy coding

Comment: Yeah, that's it. I worked wrong with the property. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a reference on the target form to write on it. 
You have to assure that you use the correct `targetForm` reference. You could either create a new `targetForm` or use an existing one. You could for example use the "parent" form of your dialog box and set the text of the main form textbox, from a dialog box event (using [this as MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k70t19bb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
Dim targetForm As Form = Me.parentForm
targetForm.targetTextBox.Text = "text"
```

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you for reply, but in my example doesn't work. I don't know why. I create formResult (which show pure result, no more functions) by Visual Studio designer, maybe this is problem. I tried in MyForm.Designer.cs change private to public TextBox ( public System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBoxResult; ), but result was same.

Comment: Thanks for help, but this way I could not have run.

Answer (score 1):

In `formResult` create a variable which keep a reference of Main form

```
private MyMainForm _mainForm;
```

Then create one more constructor which take reference of your Main form as parameter:

```
public formResult(MyMainForm mainform)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this._mainForm = mainform;
    //Now you have access to public property ResultOut
    this.textBoxResult.Text = this._mainForm.ResultOut;
}
```

After this you can use all public properties and method of your main form in second form(`formResult`)

Comment: This way, it is finally okay. I adjusted the wrong property. Thank you